# how change tab background on selected item? javascript ? or php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How change  tab background on selected item? javascript ? or php?
my code. I want when I click on Apartman 1 that this tab is selected. how to do it with javascript or php?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li ><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/index.php">Pocetna</a></li>
        <li class="active" ><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmanjedan.php">Apartman 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmandva.php">Apartman 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmantri.php">Apartman 3</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think CSS is your best bet.

Comment: You have given `class="active"` to that list item already. Are you just asking how to now style that with a background colour? Or are you asking how to *move* that class between the different list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already given an `active` class to one of the list items. To style that one with a background colour you could add a CSS style, like this:

```css
nav li.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/index.php">Pocetna</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmanjedan.php">Apartman 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmandva.php">Apartman 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmantri.php">Apartman 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

It sounds from your comment like you want help adding the `class="active"` part to the correct list item based on what page you're currently on.

That can either come from the server (each page has `class="active"` on its corresponding link in the HTML sent back from the server) or it can be set with Javascript once the page has loaded.

Setting it on the server side is going to be easiest.

How to do it depends how your pages are structured. Is this nav a common element you include into each page? I'll assume it is, and you include it on each page with `<?php include 'nav.php'; ?>` or similar.

In nav.php you could have something like the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li <?php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === '/apartmanitrifunovic/index.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/index.php">Pocetna</a></li>
      <li <?php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === '/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmanjedan.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmanjedan.php">Apartman 1</a></li>
      <li <?php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === '/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmandva.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmandva.php">Apartman 2</a></li>
      <li <?php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === '/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmantri.php') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmantri.php">Apartman 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Or, with a loop to cut down on repetition:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <?php foreach ([
        '/apartmanitrifunovic/index.php' => "Pocetna",
        '/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmanjedan.php' => "Apartman 1",
        '/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmandva.php' => "Apartman 2",
        '/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmantri.php' => "Apartman 3",
      ] as $file => $name) { ?>
        <li <?php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === $file) { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>
          <a href="http://localhost<?php echo $file; ?>">
            <?php echo $name; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Well, but I want this color to change when that particular page is active?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a PHP example of setting that class on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :active selector to change the color of the active page. You can use your active class to style the selected tab.

```
.active:active{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for:

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('li');
list.forEach(function(el){
  el.onclick=function(){
     list.forEach(function(el){
      el.classList.remove("active");
     });
     el.classList.toggle("active");
  }
});
```

```css
li.active{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li ><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/index.php">Pocetna</a></li>
        <li class="active" ><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmanjedan.php">Apartman 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmandva.php">Apartman 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://localhost/apartmanitrifunovic/apartmantri.php">Apartman 3</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Edit:**
In case you want to save the state of the clicked tab in a new page, you should use javascript to read the URL of the page where you will be passing the clicked tabName as a `GET` parameter.

```
var url_ = window.location.href;//https://example.com?tabName=Apartman%1
var c = url.searchParams.get("tabName");
document.getElementById(c).click();
```

Comment: this changes the background when I am on one page, as soon as I switch to another page, hover: active is stays on the previous tab :(

Comment: Updated the answer.